# Create FQDN in LAN for Windows systems without samba

Tags: networking, windows, samba, hostname, lan

I just set up my raspberry pi. It is working great and I can easily access it from my local Windows machine using SSH. I gave it a custom hostname. I can acces the pi with this hostname **only when** the samba server is running on the pi. When I stop it I can no longer use the custom hostname and have to use the IP.

I was wondering if there was another way Windows systems would recognize the hostname of a linux system that does not involve setting up a samba server.

This is also relevant for me since I plan on creating a dual boot system with my local machine and accessing it from another Windows system within the LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either setup a DNS server and add an entry for your Pi's hostname + IP to it. All the systems that need resolve this hostname will need to make use of this DNS server.

Your other option is to add an entry in your system's `hosts` file with an entry that specifies the Pi's hostname + IP address.

```
1.2.3.4 pi-host
```

**NOTE:** Yes Windows systems do have a host file, just like Linux/Unix systems do too.

You can see details about how to do this here: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file.

**NOTE:** This file is generally located here on Vista/Windows 7 systems: 5. In the filename field type `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.